# How to run a program autonomously on a server, how to run java program indefinitely on server?

Tags: java, jar

I have a jar executable that I'm trying to run until stop on a linux server. I've tried looking at the Java Service Wrapper API, but it was really difficult and I'm not even sure that's what I want. Is there a way I can run a program on the server so that when I log off the program keeps running? I'm using ssh to login to the server and commandline to run the jar. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks all ! No wonder stackoverflow rocks the boat, you guys are awesome ! *Question answered*

Comment: I'm glad you got an answer, but it would have been better to ask it on SuperUser.  StackOverflow is for *programming* questions ...

Comment: sorry about that, thanks for the tip, I mean, it's related to programming..it concerns running java jar executables in a linux environment, but I see what you mean. StackOverflow pops up on Google quickly, I kinda wanted to help other ppl who had the same question, but thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Run:

```
 nohup java -jar myjar.jar &
```

The ampersand at the end will run it in a new forked process, so it will continue after you log out.  `nohup` prevents it from hanging up when its owner logs out.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I'll have to check back on my program to make sure this didn't happen

Answer (score 3):

If you have the ability to set the Server as a Daemon you can do so. If not you can try to use a programm like screen to create a virtual Terminal.

```
sudo apt-get install screen
screen java -jar myJar.jar
```

if you want to reatach your terminal:

```
screen -r
```

Comment: Thank you!! haha I already knew the answer but just wanted to save someone else the horrific terror I had to go through to figure this out. Thanks kind soul!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to run it as a service, have a look at [daemontools](http://cr.yp.to/daemontools.html).

It will start your program when the machine boots, restart it if it crashes, stop it when the machine switches off.

On Ubuntu is just an apt-get away.

Answer (score 1):

Why yes there is! (keep in mind this may only work on a server and not your personal computer)
Use the linux 'screen' command to create a virtual terminal that will continue after you log off, instructions are [here](http://go2linux.garron.me/linux/2010/04/linux-screen-command-tutorial-740).

basically, use:

```
$ screen
```

to start a new virtual terminal window. Start your code, and once you get it running, type "control+a" and then "d" to detach from the window. Once you detach you can log off and your program will still be running on the server. To come back to it, type:

```
$ screen -r
```

and you'll come back to your program. Easy peasy! [Instructions](http://go2linux.garron.me/linux/2010/04/linux-screen-command-tutorial-740)